# Disable Android Keyboard Hide Animation

Tags: android, animation, keyboard, hide

I have an EditText box on my view that brings up the keyboard whenever the EditText box is being focused. The keyboard pushes the entire layout so that the EditText box is visible...as expected. When I hide the keyboard by pressing the keyboard hide button, my layout returns to its original state .i.e moves back down. This action is being animated by default however I want to disable the animation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in your manifest for your activity just remove it

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```